$f$ and $g$ injective $\implies g\circ f$ injective.
I am doing some preliminary work to study topology, and this theorem was left as an exercise in Munkre's Topology, chapter $1$. I know that similar questions about have been asked on MSE before, however I consider mine sufficiently different to those I have read to merit being asked.
Remark on notation. $ f:X\to Y $ is an injection $\equiv f:X\hookrightarrow Y $.
Theorem. If $ f:X \hookrightarrow Y $ and $ g:Y\hookrightarrow Z $ then $ g\circ f:X\hookrightarrow Z $.
Here is my proof, which I am not confident about:
Proof. Since $ f $ is a function, $f$ is a left-total relation which implies $ f(x)\in Y $ for all $ x\in X $. Let $f:X\hookrightarrow Y$. If $ g:Y\hookrightarrow Z $ also then $ g(f(x_1))=g(f(x_2)) $ implies $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ for all $f(x_1) ,f(x_2)\in Y$. Using $f:X\hookrightarrow Y$ it follows from $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ that $ x_1=x_2 $. Then $g(f(x_1))=g(f(x_2))$ implies $x_1=x_2$ for all $x_1,x_2\in X$.$[*]$ $ g(f(x)):=g\circ f(x) $ for all $ x\in X $, so $ g\circ f:X\hookrightarrow Z $. $\square$
$[*]$ Using $\psi\implies \varphi\implies \xi\equiv\psi\implies \xi$.
Here is the step I am unsure about:

If $ g:Y\hookrightarrow Z $ then $ g(f(x_1))=g(f(x_2)) $ implies$\ldots$

$f$ nor $g$ is assumed to be surjective in this theorem. Then I cannot assume for all $y\in Y$ that there exists $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$, so it initially doesn't seem proper to write $g(f(x_i))$ for $i\in \{1,2\}$ rather than $g(y_i)$.
However, here is my reasoning:
I apologise readily for using so many brackets, I am trying to be explicit. Let $G(g\circ f)\subset X\times Z$ be the graph of $g\circ f:X\to Z$ and $G(g)\subset Y\times Z$ be the graph of $g:Y\to Z$
$ (x_1,g(f(x_1))),(x_2,g(f(x_2)))\in G(g\circ f):\iff (f(x_1),g(f(x_1))), (f(x_2),g(f(x_2)))\in G(g) \land (f(x_1),g(f(x_1))),(f(x_2),g(f(x_2)))\in Y\times Z$.
Intuitively, my argument is this:

By the definition of $g\circ f$ in terms of its graph $G(g\circ f)$, the only relevant $y\in Y$ in the theorem are those $y\in Y$ such that there exists $x\in X$ such that $(x,y)\in G(f)$. Thus we can restrict our reasoning to only concern those $y\in Y$.

Is this even important, and please may I have feedback on the proof? Perhaps an explanation of this argument should be in the proof.

Your title and theorem are completely different.

@Randall I have changed it, I wrote “surjective” by accident.

Your proof is basically right but too complicated.  There is no reason to bring in "left total relations" or whatever because the definition of function is all that is needed. Also, the issue you bring up is a non-issue.  You start by assuming that you have points $x_1, x_2 \in X$ with $g(f(x_1)) = g(f(x_2))$.  You then deduce that $x_1 = x_2$ using the injectivity of $f$ and $g$, so you're done.  You never need to know that for each $y \in Y$ there is an $x \in X$ with $f(x)=y$, because that is never needed in your argument.   All this might have been clearer to you if your first line of proof was to assume $g(f(x_1)) = g(f(x_2))$ for some $x_1, x_2 \in X$.
Good exercise:  write a proof of this fact using only three sentences.

I will do your exercise. I did already consider this a convoluted proof of a simple theorem, and I’ll enjoy making a more elegant one.
